# How to add a product variant with the Ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeresource, shopify

What is the correct way to add a product variant?

I create the product successfully and it shows up in my Shopify admin. However the price is always zero and the quantity is always infinity.

I've tried creating a variant with inventory_quantity and price set, as well as with product_id set in prefix_options.

However admin is always showing price zero and quantity infinity.

```
Rails v3.2.5
shopify_api v3.0.0
shop name: vacation-2
```

I don't get errors doing the API calls. I simply don't see my variant data in the product in admin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you set the `:inventory_management` attribute to `"shopify"`, or the quantity won't persist.

I just tested this out, and it works perfectly:

```
product.variants << ShopifyAPI::Variant.new(
  :option1              => "Large",
  :price                => 12.95,
  :inventory_management => 'shopify',
  :inventory_quantity   => 10
)
product.save
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Couldn't find in documentation on Shopify but I guess that's why they have a wiki! Here is what I ended up actually using:<br/><!-- language: ruby -->shopify_listing = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(listing.shopify_id<br/>shopify_listing.update_attributes(listing_data)<br/>variant = ShopifyAPI::Variant.find(shopify_listing.variants.first.id)<br/>variant.update_attributes({inventory_quantity: listing.quantity, inventory_management: 'shopify', price: listing.price})

Answer (score 0):

Adding variants without using the products association:

```
ShopifyAPI::Variant.new(
  :product_id           =>  #enter product id,
  :option1              => "Large",
  :price                => 12.95,
  :inventory_management => 'shopify',
  :inventory_quantity   => 10
)
product.save
```

The advantage here is that variant object is updated with the values returned by the API.